# Unable to clone Git repo: Invalid file descriptor

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy, file-descriptor

I'm trying to clone a Git repository. At work we're making use of a proxy with authentication.

The commands I execute to set up the proxy settings:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy-link.nl:port-number
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy-link.nl:port-number
```

But this won't help since I'm getting the error: `Unable to access 'https://github.com/...': Invalid file descriptor`

When I change the proxy settings so that I don't have to use my authentication It works.. Like:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy-link.nl:other-port-number
git config --global https.proxy http://proxy-link.nl:other-port-number
```

Anybody knows how to use the proxy with the authentication?

Comment: So the solution is to use the last two lines?

Comment: No since I need to use the proxy with the authentication... The last two lines are a temporary hacky work around @mkrieger1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by the way a month ago by adding the `proxyAuthMethod` like below:

`git config --global http.proxyAuthMethod 'basic'` and `git config --global https.proxyAuthMethod 'basic'`